# MasterDetailsView not showing master list items despite setting properties

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

After following Microsoft's code for the `MasterDetailsView` control, the master list appears blank and doesn't show any items at all? Why has this happened and how can this be fixed?

*MasterDetailPage.xaml*

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MasterDetailPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:MyApp.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView BackButtonBehavior="Automatic" 
                                    x:Name="MyMasterDetailsView"

                                    NoSelectionContent="Select an item to view"
                                    CompactModeThresholdWidth="720">
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,8">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Opacity=".6" 
                                   MaxLines="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel Margin="24">
                        <controls:ImageEx x:Name="FromEllipse"
                                               Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
                                               Width="50"
                                               Height="50"
                                               CornerRadius="999"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="FromEllipse" 
                                   Margin="12,-6,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="SubjectLine"
                                   Text="{Binding Subject}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   RelativePanel.Below="FromEllipse"
                                   Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Body" 
                                   Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   RelativePanel.Below="SubjectLine" 
                                   Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform 
                                  ScaleX="2" 
                                  ScaleY="2"/>
                            </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </SymbolIcon>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   Margin="0,12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>

          <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Margin="12,14">
              <Run Text="{Binding Emails.Count}" />
              <Run Text="Items" />
            </TextBlock>
          </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>
      </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
      <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
        <CommandBar>
          <AppBarButton Icon="MailReply" Label="Reply" />
          <AppBarButton Icon="MailReplyAll" Label="Reply All" />
          <AppBarButton Icon="MailForward" Label="Forward" />
        </CommandBar>
      </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

*MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs*

```
    public sealed partial class MasterDetailPage: Page
    {
        public MasterDetailPage()
        {    
            this.InitializeComponent();

        Binding myBinding = new Binding()
        {
            Source = Emails,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };

        MyMasterDetailsView.SetBinding(MasterDetailsView.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);

            var emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
            emails.ForEach(email => Emails.Add(email));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Email> Emails = new ObservableCollection<Email>();

        public void OnXamlRendered(FrameworkElement control)
        {
            control.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

*Email.cs*

```
    public class Email
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyEmailManager
    {
        public static List<Email> GetEmails()
        {
            var MyEmails = new List<Email>
            {
                new Email
                {
                    From = "Steve Johnson",
                    Body = "Are you available for lunch tomorrow? A client would like to discuss a project with you."
                },
                new Email
                {
                    From = "Pete Davidson",
                    Body = "Don't forget the kids have their soccer game this Friday. We have to supply end of game snacks."
                },
                new Email
                {
                    From = "OneDrive",
                    Body = "Your new album.\r\nYou uploaded some photos to yuor OneDrive and automatically created an album for you."
                },
                new Email
                {
                    From = "Twitter",
                    Body = "Here are some people we think you might like to follow:\r\n.@randomPerson\r\nAPersonYouMightKnow"
                }
            };

            return MyEmails;
        }
    }
```

*Current result*

[image: Blank Master Details View]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, you did not assign a value to the `Emails` variable, please try the following code:

```cs
public MasterDetailPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
    emails.ForEach(email => Emails.Add(email));
}

public ObservableCollection<Email> Emails = new ObservableCollection<Email>();

// other code
```

Due to the modification of the collection, you need to notify the UI to make changes, so it is recommended to use **ObservableCollection** instead of **ICollection**, and get the Email entry through `MyEmailManager` and add it to the collection.

In MasterDetailsView of XAML, binding `Emails` are required:

```xml
<controls:MasterDetailsView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"
                            ...>
  <!-- content code -->
</controls:MasterDetailsView>
```

In WindowsCommunityToolkit, the complete Xaml and C# code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/MasterDetailsView)

Thanks.

Comment: Code changes are now causing a `null` error. Please see the latest screenshot + my XAML page code.

Comment: Sorry, I have modified the answer. Initialize when creating `Emails`

Comment: No worries. This is a weird issue. The app no longer crashes but the list still appears blank.

Comment: Hello, please change `{Binding Emails}` in Xaml to `{x:Bind Emails}`. After leaving the application environment of WindowsCommunityToolkit, we need to modify the binding method.

Comment: Hello again. Using `{x:Bind Emails}` in my XAML did not work for me, unfortunately. Please see my latest screenshot.

Comment: Hello, I can't reproduce your problem, can you update your code so that I can analyze it?

Comment: In `MasterDetailPage.xaml` I changed `Binding Emails` to `x:Bind Emails`

Comment: Hello, did you initialize Emails in code-behind? `public ObservableCollection<Email> Emails = new ObservableCollecton<Email>();`

Comment: Hello, yes I did that underneath the constructor. Code has been updated. Also, the sample does not help much because a `.bind` file is being used.

Comment: Hello, I created a new blank application and copied your current code on the page (removed the `OnXamlRendered` method because no reference is needed). New projects do not need `.bind` files. You can try to create a new blank page to see if this problem can be reproduced. If so, please post this minimum runnable demo on Github or OneDrive and share the link, so that I can check the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi. I created a demo in Github which you can see in [this link](https://github.com/macaronlover/MD)

Comment: Hello, in the code you provided, you need to modify two places: 1. MasterDetailsView.ItemsSource changed to `{x:Bind Emails}`, which is still `{Binding Emails}`. 2. You have added an additional TextBlock that displays **Subject** in `MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate`, but you have not defined the **Subject** property in the Email class, and also do not include `Brush-Blue-01` in the application resources. This is the reason for the error when running the application, please delete this TextBlock, or add the corresponding property and resource.

Comment: Could you also confirm the correct way to use `x:Bind` programmatically? My code has been updated but I don't understand/know what needs to go in the `'Source'` part. `ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"` has been manually removed.

Comment: Hello, based on the code you showed, you should bind the collection to `ItemsSourceProperty`, not `ItemsPanelProperty`

Comment: In the case that `Path` has been set, Source is not necessary, for details, please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#creating-bindings-in-code)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work and now the master column appears blank. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Please try to replace `Path = new PropertyPath("Emails")` with `Source = Emails`, that is, use **Source** to replace **Path**, please refer to the table about the correspondence between `Feature` and `x:Bind` in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#xbind-and-binding-feature-comparison)

Comment: Hello again. I did follow the document and I replaced `Path = new PropertyPath("Emails")` with `Source = Emails`, but the master list view still appears blank. I have updated my c# code.

Comment: Hello, I can't reproduce this problem, can you provide another demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hello. You can find a demo on my [Github directory](https://github.com/macaronlover/MD)

Comment: Hello, I tested your demo and it works fine. You can try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders inside the project and rebuild the project